# Getting errors while installing Opengraph Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, facebook-opengraph

I get the following error when I try to install the opengraph gem:

```
gem install opengraphBuilding native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing opengraph:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-xslt-dir
    --without-xslt-dir
    --with-xslt-include
    --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
    --with-xslt-lib
    --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib


Gem files will remain installed in /home/faraz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/nokogiri-1.4.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/faraz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/nokogiri-1.4.7/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

Here is my setup:

- OS: Linux Mint 64bit.
- Ruby: 1.9.3
- Rails 3.2.3
- Rubygems: 2.1.0

Please help.

**EDIT**

As asked in the answer below, here are the logs from `/home/faraz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/nokogiri-1.4.7/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out`:

```
....../bin/ruby extconf.rb extconf.rb:10: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... no
 ----- libxslt is missing
```

There are some other lines like this in the log file.

Comment: I am unable to post full error code, stackoverflow is saying your question full of code, add details.

Comment: Highlight the code and select the { } button

Comment: You don't need to add all of the error, the next few lines should be sufficient. Also, mention the OS you are using and the gem version.

Comment: Gem -v gives me version 2.1.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the above log, it should be clear that opengraph installation failed because nokigiri installation failed. You should next open `/home/faraz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/nokogiri-1.4.7/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out` and tell us the error logged there. I have a hunch that you don't have xml tools on your machine. Log messages from that file will confirm it.

To install nokogiri, you need to have some packages installed already: Run the following command to install them now:

```
sudo apt-get install libxslt1-dev libxml2-dev
```

After that, run `gem install nokogiri` and if there are any errors, please report them again. If not, you can go back to installing opengraph.

Comment: ....../bin/ruby extconf.rb
extconf.rb:10: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... no
-----
libxslt is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
 --with-opt-dir
 --without-opt-dir

Comment: these are some lines inlog file, they appear to be same

Comment: Thanks a lot, i followed your steps and opengraph has installed now. Thank you soo much.